# How to use new Android 2.0 Shrinker and Resource Shrinker together?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to use the new Shrinker for debug builds (at 3:14)

https://youtu.be/xxx3Fn7EowU?t=3m14s

Also I want to enable shrinking unused resources after that.

My config is

```
        debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

But Gradle sync fails with an error message:

> Error:Build-in class shrinker and resource shrinking are not supported yet.

Is this possible or I need to enable full proguard to use resource shrinking?

Comment: are you doing a `debug` build type?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue . How did you solved it ?

Comment: @karthikkolanji I haven't tried since then, but it seems that there is no solution yet

Comment: @karthikkolanji Now I get "Error:Build-in class shrinker and multidex are not supported yet."

Comment: Error:Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on. See http://d.android.com/r/tools/shrink-resources.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan R is completely right.
Just small addition. You could either completely remove `useProguard false` string from your `buildType`closure, or set it to `useProguard true` if you are in release build type.

Comment: I have tried again. Now I get this error: Minifying the variant used for tests is not supported when using Jack.

Comment: Accordint to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314760/android-how-to-perform-obfuscation-with-the-jack-compiler/37326896#37326896) minifying is not supported in debug buldType. Try yo use it in release mode. Also everything will work fine if you disable Jack compiler, even in debug mode. I still haven't migrated to Jack because its using leads to a lot of troubles now.

Comment: Will give it a try. Yeah, but in order to use the new Java 8 language features like Lambda and Method references, you need to use the Jack toolchain.

Comment: I have tried again..It works only if you also enable code shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to disable `useProguard false` and it was able to build.